# Manually calling System.GC.Collect() changes action of Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, garbage-collection

I believed that manually calling System.GC.Collect() only effect performance or memory usage of application. But in this example, calling System.GC.Collect() changes application's action.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Click += Form1_Click;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateMyEventHandler()(sender, e);
        //System.GC.Collect();
    }

    private EventHandler CreateMyEventHandler()
    {
        return (sender, e) =>
        {
            var cm = new ContextMenu(new[] 
                {
                    new MenuItem("Menu item", (sender2, e2) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Menu item is clicked!");
                    })
                });
            cm.Show(this, ((MouseEventArgs)e).Location);
        };
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Save above code into a file "Program.cs" and run it as following.

```
csc Program.cs
.\Program.exe
```

It opens window as figure below.

[image: sample code]

Clicking the window opens context menu, and clicking the menu item prints text massage "Menu item is clicked!" to the console, as expected.

However, with uncommenting the line commented out in above example:

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

The action of application changes. Clicking menu item prints nothing.

This was unexpected for me. So why it changes? And how do I prevent unexpected change of this kind in real application?

This example is confirmed with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Why are you creating a new event handler every time the form is clicked? That's strange.

Comment: I am writing an app like MSPaint, which acts as state machine driven by mouse events. The app has an instance variable named State : EventHandler that receives any kind of mouse event(Move, Click, Leave, etc.). And state transition is done by switching the event handler, by creating new EventHandler instance and assign it to variable State. So this example is simplified version of that app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a premature collection problem.  You can see that for yourself by adding this class:

```
class MyContextMenu : ContextMenu {
    public MyContextMenu(MenuItem[] items) : base(items) { }
    ~MyContextMenu() {
        Console.WriteLine("Oops");
    }
}
```

And using MyContextMenu instead of ContextMenu.  Note how you see "Oops" when you call GC.Collect().

There is a technical reason for this, ContextMenu is a .NET 1.x class that wraps the native menus built into the OS.  It does not derive from the Control class so does not participate in the normal way controls are kept alive.  Which is through an internal table inside the Winforms plumbing that ensures that Control objects stay referenced as long as their native Handle exists.  This same kind of table is missing for Menu class.  It gets extra confusing because the .NET wrapper class is gone but the native Windows menu still exists, so *seems* to operate correctly.

Back in the .NET 1.x days programmers were used to using the designer to create context menus.  Which works fine, they stay referenced through the *components* collection.  Which is how you could fix this problem:

```
    var cm = new ContextMenu(...);
    this.components.Add(cm);
    cm.Show(this, ((MouseEventArgs)e).Location);
```

Albeit that you now keep adding context menus, that isn't pretty either.  Assigning the form's ContextMenu property is another workaround, probably the one you prefer.  But, really rather best to retire this ancient 1.x component and use ContextMenuStrip instead, it doesn't have this problem:

```
    var cm = new ContextMenuStrip();
    cm.Items.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new ToolStripMenuItem("Menu item", null, (sender2, e2) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu item is clicked!");
        })
    });
    cm.Show(this, ((MouseEventArgs)e).Location);
```

Comment: Ah, that's why the menu is not keeping itself rooted. Pretty much an oversight.

Comment: There can also be issues if "Dispose" is not called on controls because they are not put into the components collection.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody is keeping a reference of your context menu and its menu item.
If you are forcing the garbage collector to run, it will detect that and remove them. 
If you don't force the garbage collector, these items will be garbage collected too, but later, which is why you see the printing.

Comment: This seems to be a bug or quality of implementation problem with WinForms. The explanation given here is probably correct from a technical standpoint but that behavior is just stupid by WinForms.

Comment: @usr: how is it a bug? If you don't keep a reference to something, then it's garbage. That's how it works throughout the entirety of .NET. Nothing new and nothing unexpected.

Comment: @siride the menu could simply keep itself alive. Timers do that, forms do that.

Comment: @usr: that's also bizarre behavior, and timers require special code to do that. It's a hack, not a proper solution.

Comment: I hoped GC to keep menu/menuitem objects uncollected while they are visible and clickable. But anyway, they are being collected. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @siride it's what everybody wants and it's not unusual. There have to be *some* roots. Threads are roots as well. Why not kill a thread when its `Thread` is collected? Because nobody wants that.

Comment: @usr if it needs to be connected to a root, there are very straightforward ways to do that that fit entirely within the normal paradigm of the language. Otherwise, you end up with objects that bizarrely don't ever clean themselves up because they are self-rooted or something like that, and that's a memory leak. Not the right answer.